# Requesting help for monitoring data drift in instance segmentation model

Tags: computer-vision

happy to be here.

I need some guidance. I am writing a project on data drift. I have trained an instance segmentation model on the Cityscapes Dataset, to detect pedestrians. The model I trained was on daylight images, and I have exported the same. But now I want to build the drift monitoring solution to pick up data drift when I test the model on nighttime images of pedestrians. I have tried using alibi-detect, scikit multiflow but struggled to make any progress.
For Daytime images: cityscape
For nighttime images: nightowl

I will be extremely grateful for any help. Thank you.